# OnAfterRender or OnInitializedAsync function to refresh data?

Tags: timer, blazor, refresh

I'd like to refresh my data each minute. for this, I use a timer.

`

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
        //Configuration des graphiques
        Alert.Info("OnInitializedAsync");
        timer = new System.Threading.Timer(async (object? stateInfo) =>
         { 
             loading = true;
             GetDataAPI(); 
         }, new System.Threading.AutoResetEvent(false), 2000, 2000);
}
```

`
this work fine, but when I load the page for the fisrt time, It spend a long time before to load data. when I delete the Time it's very faster.

so my question, is it in the OnInitializedAsync that I use the timer ? I've read a lot of documention on the cycle but don't really see the difference between OnAfterRender or OnInitializedAsync.

should I load data the first time in OnAfterRender with FirstRender ? and then the timer in OnInitializedAsync ?

thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you load data in OnAfterRender, wouldn't it make sense to load it OnInitialisedAsync, before the render?

Comment: because the data took too long to load

Comment: What do you mean by "a long time" ? Is it around 2 seconds? Because you seem to be unnecessarily waiting 2 seconds before your first execution of the Timer (`dueTime`: 3rd argument of the constructor).

Comment: If the data takes long to load, wouldn't it be better to render a spinner first? Or some message along the lines "data is being loaded, please wait..."

Comment: It take 23sec...

Comment: I have a spinner to load data but 23 sec for the first time instead of 2 sec it's strange ....

Comment: Depends on what you do in GetDataAPI(). I would start with timing this function.

Comment: It get data like this. `ListeObjectif = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Models.Objectif>>("api/objectifs");`

Comment: @Maysa Are you positive that you are hiding the spinner and displaying data when you finished fetching data: is the rerender actually done at the end of each timer execution?

Answer (score 1):

You can break out the timer into a separate class with an event to drive updates:

```cs
public class MyTimer
{
    private System.Timers.Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    
    public event EventHandler<ElapsedEventArgs>? TimerElapsed;
    
    public MyTimer(double period)
       => SetTimer(period);
    
    private void SetTimer(double period)
    {
        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(period);
        _timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        _timer.AutoReset = true;
        _timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void OnTimedEvent(object? source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        => this.TimerElapsed?.Invoke(this, e);

}
```

And then you can use it like this.  I've added a simple message that is updated every 5 seconds to demo getting new data.  Note there's no delay on the initial load.

```cs
@page "/"
@implements IDisposable

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<div class="alert alert-info">
    @message
</div>

@code {
    private MyTimer? timer;
    private string message = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    private bool isGettingData;

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await this.GetDataAsync();

        // Set for every 5 seconds
        timer = new(5000);
        timer.TimerElapsed += this.OnTimeElapsed;
    }

    private async void OnTimeElapsed(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await this.GetDataAsync();
        // Update the UI
        await this.InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

    private async ValueTask GetDataAsync()
    {
        // Only get the data again if we finished the last get
        if (isGettingData)
            return;

        isGettingData = true;
        // emulate async fetching data
        await Task.Delay(100);
        message = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        isGettingData = false;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (timer is not null)
            timer.TimerElapsed -= this.OnTimeElapsed;

        timer = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use OnParameterSet() instead of OnInitialize()